# Selenium portable Chrome opening CMD

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

Why is selenium opening a cmd with Portable Chrome like this.

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PagoN.png)

Can I hide this or can I start portable chrome always on top? Because I am using autoit for proxy proxy authentication but this cmd is on top sometime. I am sending alt + tab with autoit for select chrome but sometime chrome is on top.

my code :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
    options.addArguments("--lang=en");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1078,924");
    options.setBinary("E:\\Chromelar\\Chrome1\\GoogleChromePortable.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\SelenimuDriver\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. In your portable installation, you should have an App/Chrome-bin/ folder where a chrome.exe is located. It looks like that way on my system.

```
[...]\GoogleChromePortable64\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe
```

So try to find the chrome.exe, it should be something like

```
options.setBinary("E:\\Chromelar\\Chrome1\\App\\Chrome-bin\\chrome.exe");
```

After executing this chrome.exe instead of GoogleChromePortable.exe, the cmd was gone. I did it with the ChromeWebDriver version 81.